# Import Users with properties, to include msDS-cloudextensionattribute1

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory

I have a script that works well with all other attributes. I don't understand how to make this happen. I am a novice to scripting. I have an import that works well until I add `msDS-cloudExtensionAttribute1`. I also need to add a couple of more. Thanks for a look over.

```
#Import active directory module for running AD cmdlets
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

#Store the data from ADUsers.csv in the $ADUsers variable
$Users = Import-csv C:\Test\TESTUSER3a.csv


#Loop through each row containing user details in the CSV file 

foreach ($User in $Users)



 {
    # Read user data from each field in each row
    # the username is used more often, so to prevent typing, save that in a variable
   $Username       = $User.SamAccountName
   
   }
  

    # Check to see if the user already exists in AD
    if (Get-ADUser -F {SamAccountName -eq $Username}) {
         #If user does exist, give a warning
         Write-Warning "A user account with username $Username already exist in Active Directory."
    }
    else {
        # User does not exist then proceed to create the new user account

        # create a hashtable for splatting the parameters
       

        $userProps = @{
            SamAccountName             = $User.SamAccountName                   
            Path                       = $User.path      
            GivenName                  = $User.GivenName 
            Surname                    = $User.Surname
            Initials                   = $User.Initials
            Name                       = $User.Name
            DisplayName                = $User.DisplayName
            UserPrincipalName          = $user.UserPrincipalName 
            Department                 = $User.Department
            Description                = $User.Description
            Office                     = $User.Office
            OfficePhone                = $User.OfficePhone
            EmailAddress               = $User.EmailAddress
            StreetAddress              = $User.StreetAddress
            POBox                      = $User.POBox
            City                       = $User.City
            State                      = $User.State
            PostalCode                 = $User.PostalCode
            Title                      = $User.Title
            Company                    = $User.Company
            msDS-cloudExtensionAttribute1 = $User.msDS-cloudExtensionattribute1
            # AccountPassword            = (ConvertTo-SecureString $User.password -AsPlainText -Force) 
            Enabled                    = $false
            ChangePasswordAtLogon      = $false
        }   #end userprops   
}
         New-ADUser @userProps
         Write-Host "The user account $User is created." -ForegroundColor Cyan
   

     #end else
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is my working solution.

$Users |
foreach {
Set-ADUser $User.SamAccountName -Replace @{'msDS-cloudExtensionAttribute1'=$*.GGGG} Set-ADUser $User.SamAccountName -Replace @{'msDS-cloudExtensionAttribute2'=$*.PK} Set-ADUser $User.SamAccountName -Replace @{'msDS-cloudExtensionAttribute3'=$_.OK}

Comment: Thanks for posting an answer. Please [format your post properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).
Your answer doesn't match your question, however: A `New-ADUser` call is missing. It is unclear where the `$User` variable
comes from - it looks like you meant to use `$_`. Unlike in the question, you're trying to set _multiple_ extension attributes.
In short: your answer is likely to confuse future readers.

Comment: As for the solution itself: You don't need _multiple_ `Set-ADUser` calls to set multiple extension attributes - just use multiple entries in a single hash table.
Similarly, going back to the original requirement: As suggested in the other answers, a single `New-ADUser` call that sets the extension attributes using `-OtherAttributes` 
(via a nested `OtherAttributes` entry in the hash table used for splatting) should do.

Comment: Yes, as I also mentioned in my answer, you can do multiple `Otherattributes` at once in the hashtable (or command line) if you separate them with semicolons: `Otherattributes  = @{'msDS-cloudExtensionAttribute1'="$User.msDS-cloudExtensionattribute1";msDS-cloudExtensionAttribute2'="$User.msDS-cloudExtensionattribute2";anyAttribute="valid input"}`

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the [New-Aduser command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/activedirectory/new-aduser?view=windowsserver2022-ps), it has lengthy list of parameters, including all the common attributes for creating an account. But there are many user attributes, including `msDS-cloudExtensionAttribute1` that are not parameters to this command.

What you're doing with your hashtable is substituting its contents for the individual parameters in the command:

```
New-Aduser -SamAccountName $User.SamAccountName -Path $User.path `
-GivenName $User.GivenName -Surname $User.Surname ...
```

Since the `msDS-cloudExtensionAttribute1` attribute is not in the default `New-Aduser` parameter list, it needs to be added using the `-Otherattributes` parameter. This is its own hashtable of attribute name and value pairs. You can include multiple attributes separated by semicolons. You still need the quotes around the attribute name because of the dash: `-Otherattributes = @{'msDS-cloudExtensionAttribute1'="testing"}`

In a hashtable of parameters, it should look like the below:

```
$userProps = @{
    SamAccountName         = "TestTest2"               
    Path                   = "OU=TEST,DC=example,DC=net"  
    GivenName              = "Test"
    Surname                = "test2"
    Name                   = "TestTest2"
    AccountPassword        = (ConvertTo-SecureString $pass -AsPlainText -Force) 
    Enabled                = $false
    ChangePasswordAtLogon  = $true
    Otherattributes        = @{'msDS-cloudExtensionAttribute1'="testing"}
}
New-ADUser @userProps
```

(Just as a note, it's always good to simplify things when troubleshooting by just using text input and the minimal number of parameters to create the account.)

Comment: Also, I'd be cautious using the `msDS-cloudextensionAttributes`. They're really intended to be updated in Azure, and I spotted one recently being used by an Azure feature that we had not populated (can't remember which, sorry). Obviously they're synched on-prem, but more for reading than writing, is my impression. We stick to the `extensionAttributes`

Comment: Thank you very much. I have been trying with no success. I am trying to import a csv. I can use the Otherattributes per user, but I am trying to bulk import.

Comment: Yes re the CSV, but I really meant that it's easiest to troubleshoot if you try with one user first, focusing on the problem attribute. Once the main `New-Aduser` function works with with one account, then the CSV processing should work fine. 
So, if you compare with your original script, all you literally need to do is substitute `Otherattributes  = @{'msDS-cloudExtensionAttribute1'="$User.msDS-cloudExtensionattribute1"}` where you define `msDS-cloudExtensionAttribute1` in the hashtable.

Answer (score 0):

You hashtable key and property name `msDS-cloudExtensionattribute1` contains `-`, which is syntactically interpreted as the `-` *operator* (subtraction), and therefore breaks an expression such as `$User.msDS-cloudExtensionattribute1`

**To make PowerShell recognize `msDS-cloudExtensionattribute1` *as a whole*** key / name:

- as a **[hashtable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/abou:t/about_Hash_Tables) key**:

  - Enclose the (literal) property name in `'...'`:

    ```bash
    @{ 'msDS-cloudExtensionattribute1' = 'foo' }
    ```
- as a **property name**:

  - Enclose the property name in `'...'` (works in *both* PowerShell editions):

    ```bash
    $User.'msDS-cloudExtensionattribute1'
    ```
  - *[Best avoided]* You may alternatively enclose the name in `{...}` analogous to how *variable* names can be specified unambiguously; however, technically this works differently and incurs overhead: the `{...}` enclosure creates a [*script block*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Script_Blocks) which is then *implicitly stringified*, resulting in its verbatim content (excluding `{` and `}`, but including incidental whitespace), which is then used as the property name:

    ```bash
    # Works, but is inefficient.
    $User.{msDS-cloudExtensionattribute1}
    ```

---

Note that **PowerShell more generally allows you to specify property (member) names *indirectly*, via *variables* and *explicit* expressions** using `(...)`, the [grouping operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#grouping-operator--).

Thus, the following would work too:

```bash
# Using a variable:
$propName = 'msDS-cloudExtensionattribute1'
$User.$propName

# Using an explicit expression (contrived example):
$User.( 'msDS' + '-' + 'cloudExtensionattribute1' )
```

---

***Separately*, your attempt at using [splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Splatting) with [`New-AdUser`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/activedirectory/new-aduser) cannot work as such**, because there is *no* parameter named `-msDS-cloudExtensionattribute1` (which wouldn't be a valid parameter name).

Instead, extended attributes must be passed via a (nested) *hashtable* passed to the `-OtherAttributes` parameter.

Thus, you need something like the following:

```bash
$userProps = @{
  SamAccountName             = $User.SamAccountName                   
  # ... 
  OtherAttributes = @{ 'msDS-cloudExtensionAttribute1' = $User.'msDS-cloudExtensionattribute1' }
  # ...
}
```

Comment: No worries, @LeeM. Your answer is more detailed regarding the crux of the problem; I was focused on the syntax problems with the hash-table keys and property names (that problem was temporarily edited out of the question, after this answer had been posted), and only later noticed the need for a nested hashtable to target `-OtherAttributes`. It's unfortunate that neither of our answers was accepted, and that the accepted one is suboptimal and doesn't match the question. I cannot personally verify that our answers work, but I would expect them to.